# Upgraded Qt5.4.1 to 5.12.1, and now QCodec gives an exception

Tags: c++, qt, process, qt5, qprocess

I've "inherited" a project which was working fine but we upgraded it to work with visual studio 2015 and qt 5.12.1.

But for some reason it gives an exception now. What it basically does is it checks a location in regedit (which is written from another application) and reads a string value (which records the users). The query it does is :

**CMD:**

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 /user: "User" /password:"Password" class stdregprov call GetStringValue hDefKey="&H80000007" sSubKeyName=Software\Company\ApplicationServer sValueName=USERS"
```

When I run this from cmd it returns a result and gives the same result in application too.

The return value is
**OUT:**

```
Executing (stdregprov)->GetStringValue()

Method execution successful.

Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
  ReturnValue = 0;
  sValue = "";
}
```

But when it tries the codec in the code below, it gives an Access Violation Exception. Note that cmd is the parameters we sent to cmd (as shown above) and out is the response (as its shown above too).

```
void MyUtil::runProcess(QString& cmd, QString& out, QString& arr){

QProcess process;
process.start(cmd);
proces.waitForFinished(osProcessTimeout*1000);

if(cmd.contains("sValueName=USERS")){ //which is true for our problem
QByteArray arr = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("857");
out = codec->toUnicode(arr);   // ----> WHERE IT GIVES THE EXCEPTION

}else{

out = process.readAllStandardOutput();

}

err = process.readAllStandardError();

}
```

Comment: What is `codec` at that line? I would presume it's null, which would be an error.

Comment: @ChrisMM yes kind of, its `""` but not null

Comment: `codec` is a pointer … it can't be `""` … It is a memory address … https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html Your codec name of `857` doesn't appear to be valid; unless it's a custom one you made?

Comment: @ChrisMM what do you suggest best solution to be? And should I see a codec declaration of "857" in any part of code for it to be valid? Because there is not. And is there a standard codec declaration that would help, like codecForLocale();

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale returns the codec for your current local, and is likely what you want. codecForName is for if you want a specific codec.

Comment: Well damn, it worked. If you post it as an answer I'd accept it my dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`codec` is likely nullptr, since it cannot find a codec with a name of `857` … https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html Your codec name of 857 doesn't appear to be valid; unless it's a custom one you made. You should probably be using `codecForLocale`, unless you want a specific codec, in which case you would need it's proper "Qt" name